# Calculating workout energy burned per rep

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential

I received this machine as a gift. Now, the name is a bit ridiculous and implies I only need to use it 5 minutes per day in order to slim. From a physics perspective that doesn't make any sense. In order to slim, your calorie intake needs to be less than your calorie burn. So I decided to bust out the math and physics and try to calculate how many calories a rep burns on this thing and figure out how many reps I need to do per day.

Here's the device.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpkNGBsX4No

My take on this is it lifts your middle section. I am assuming my lower body weights about half of my total body mass

```
m = mbody * 0.5 = 65kg * 0.5 = 32.5
```

The device lifts that mass about 30 centimeters, so potential energy to lift is:

```
E = m*g*h = 32.5 * 9.8 * 0.3 = 95.55 Joules = 0.022 kcal or 0.022 food calories
```

A can of coke has 100 food cal, so that results tells me I have to do 4545 reps on the machine to burn a can of coke. Something is off, or reality is simply that harsh. Where are my calculations going wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note: I am neglecting friction and the horizontal component of the movement (which, without friction would zero out anyway I think?) I don't think they could explain why my calculations result in such low energy consumption.

Comment: I haven't looked at it in detail but two things spring to mind: first of all you are assuming what you are doing is completely efficient which is far from true.  *However* it is known to be the case that, unless you do really extreme amounts of exercise you don't burn enough energy to lose weight: if you want to get thinner you really do need to eat less unless you're running marathons or something, because there's a lot of energy in food. So your result is plausible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! Can you link to any research? It is frustrating how many people say you need to exercise, but the math doesn't add up to me.

Comment: To give an idea just how much exercise needs to be done to burn off *some* calories: *"Typically, a person must take 26,471 steps to burn 1,000 calories. On average, a total of 2,250 steps is equivalent to 1 mile. A 160-pound person walking at a pace of 3 miles per hour burns 85 calories per mile and 255 per hour."* https://www.reference.com/health/many-steps-burn-1000-calories-cb780cf847073dbd . Machines like yours can definitely work to *tone* muscle but are impractical to burn calories on. Yes, reality is *that harsh*!

Comment: There is research that suggest short bursts of intense exercise can raise your metabolic rate, such that you begin to burn calories more quickly whilst not exercising. However, I agree with the other comments - unless you are doing aerobic exercise for literally hours, the direct calorie consumption from the exercise is fairly insignificant - about 400-500 calories per hour if you run at a fair pace.